# Remove item from items array

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Remove item from items array and return new list array**

> list: [
>           {
>             "id": 1,
>             "name": "john",
>             "items": [
>               {
>                 "id": 2,
>                 "name": "michael",
>               },
>     {
>                 "id": 3,
>                 "name": "mohamed",
>               }
>   }]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not at all clear. You want to remove item from items array, but with respect to what you haven't mentioned. So I provided that condition myself. My code removes items based on the given id. If id is 2 the object inside the items array removes the object which has the id property set to 2.

```
var list= 
[ 
    { "id": 1, "name": "john", "items": 
    [ { "id": 2, "name": "michael", },
     { "id": 3, "name": "mohamed", } ]}]
var id=2;
     var r=list.forEach((w)=>{
          w.items.forEach((u)=>{
              if(u.id==id)
              {w.items.splice(w.items.indexOf(u),1);}
          })
             })
             console.log(list[0].items[0]);
```